# How to "merge" two Python twisted applications?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, tornado, reactor

I have two applications, written on twisted framework, for example one using twisted.web, and other using twisted.protocols.*, not web. How can I "merge" them in one, effectively sharing one reactor for both apps?

What are the best practices for that tasks? Actually I need to connect SIPSimpleApp and TornadoWeb. They both can use twisted reactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a twisted application you can install more than one protocol-factory-client instance

Twisted will handle connection for all application.

So you can instanciate as server/client as you want and , you're right , reactor.run() must be launch only one time.

So you can import your protocole and thant run the reactor loop .
exemple based on the simpliest echo example:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

class Echo2(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data+" From 2")

class EchoFactory2(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo2()

reactor.listenTCP(1234, EchoFactory())

reactor.listenTCP(1235, EchoFactory2())
reactor.run()
```

that's work

You can also use twistd system, and the service collection, documentation [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html)

Answer (score 0):

So far I found, that if you merge two twisted applications, you should remove reactor.run() from one of them, leaving only one reactor.run() in the end. And be sure that twisted.reactor implementation is same for both applications.
More comments welcome.